# Calling an asmx web service from Xamarin Forms

Tags: web-services, xamarin.forms

I am developing an Xamarin Forms application and I would to call an ASMX web service. I tried to add the service reference but Xamarin is adding it as a WCF service.

Is there another way to call the methods on this service? Such as in ASP.NET I am able to call it natively.

Any ideas here would be most appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/asmx

Comment: i think this article explains more about the service itself. my service is already coded and ready for use. i would like to call some of the methods on it. how is that done?

Comment: if you read the entire thing it contains multiple sections on creating the proxy service and calling the methods from your client